# Print string backwards using linkedlist C+

Tags: c++, string, linked-list, reverse, singly-linked-list

OK, well I'm ready to get schooled and insulted. I must make a simple program that accepts a string and prints it backewards using linked list. Below is my implementation, I tried testing it by printing the first node, but nothing appears. Why is this so?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

void addNode(char x);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
    string text;
    std::cout<<"Insert texst to see it backwards: ";
    std::cin >> text;

    //convert string to char array
    char ctext[1024];
    strcpy(ctext, text.c_str());

}
class Node{
      friend class LinkedList;
    private:
        string data;
        Node *pnext;

    public:

        //general constructor
        Node(void):pnext(NULL)
        {}

        //constructor with data value
        Node(string val):data(val),pnext(NULL)
        {}
        //constructor with data and next values
        Node(string val, Node* next):data(val), pnext(next)
        {}

        //Getters
        string getValue(void){
            return data;
        }

        Node* getNext(void){
            return pnext;
        }

};

class LinkedList
{
    private:

        Node *head;
        Node *tail;

    public:
        LinkedList(void); //general constructor
        LinkedList(string val);//constructor with value of a list node

        void addNode(char* x);
};

LinkedList::LinkedList(){
    head = tail = NULL;
}

LinkedList::LinkedList(string val){
    head = new Node(val);
    tail = head;
}

void LinkedList::addNode(char* x){

    if (head == NULL){
        tail = head= new Node(x[0]);
    }
    else{
    int i = 0;
    while (x[i]!=NULL){
        //creat new node with value
        Node* tmp = new Node(x[i]);
        //tmp node points to head
        tmp->pnext = head;
        //tmp becomes new head
        head=tmp;
        i++;
    }
    Node *p = head;
    std::cout<<p->data;



}
}
```

Comment: Why use a linked list? Why even create your own `list`? Just use `crbegin()` and `crend()`.

Comment: Because this is for a class lolol, I mean I would do that. But I need to show I can do it by my self I guess.

Comment: Isn't each node supposed to contain a single character not a string? Otherwise how would the list help you reverse the string?

Comment: Yea, your right. I will change that.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact you never create a list or put anything in it...

You test if the list has no nodes in it:

```
if (head == NULL)
```

This will be true, because it is the first insertion. Then you create one node:

```
tail = head= new Node(x[0]);
```

Then that's it. Your `if` block ends there, and skips to the end of the `if-else` where there are no more statements, just the end brace of the function body. You probably didn't want to use an `if-else` and just an `if`.

```
int i = 0;
if (head == NULL)
{
    tail = head= new Node(x[0]);
    i = 1;
}
```

Just make sure you check if the string is longer than one character.

Comment: Dam, ty. this is demoralizing

Comment: nullptr was not declared in this scope error - line 26

Comment: " - line 48
ranged based for loops are not allowd in c++98 -
nulptr not declared line 24

Comment: @RED LIGHTER sounds like your compiler is stuck in the last century. Try compiling with support for c++11 at least.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you need a stack. You could use standard container `std::forward_list` to output a string in the reverse order using a list. Or of course you could use the standard container adapter `std::stack`.

If you need to write the list yourself then the program can look something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class LinkedList
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        char data;
        Node *next;
    } *head;
public:
    LinkedList() : head( nullptr ) {}
    LinkedList( const std::string &s ) : head( nullptr )
    {
        for ( char c : s ) push_front( c );
    }
    ~LinkedList()
    {
        while ( head )
        {
            Node *current = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete current;
        }
    }        
    void push_front( char c )
    {
        head = new Node { c, head };
    }        
    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &, const LinkedList & );
};

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const LinkedList &lst )
{
    for ( LinkedList::Node *current = lst.head; current; current = current->next )
    {
        os << current->data;
    }

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s( "Hello World!" );
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    LinkedList lst( s );
    std::cout << lst << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World!
!dlroW olleH
```

You can add your own methods to the list if you want. For example you could add methods like `clear` or `reset`.

Here is the same class with added methods `front` and `pop_front`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class LinkedList
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        char data;
        Node *next;
    } *head;
public:
    LinkedList() : head( nullptr ) {}
    LinkedList( const std::string &s ) : head( nullptr )
    {
        for ( char c : s ) push_front( c );
    }
    ~LinkedList()
    {
        while ( head )
        {
            Node *current = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete current;
        }
    }
    LinkedList( const LinkedList & ) = delete;
    LinkedList & operator =( const LinkedList & ) = delete;
    void push_front( char c )
    {
        head = new Node { c, head };
    } 
    bool empty() const
    {
        return head == nullptr;
    }
    void pop_front()
    {
        if ( !empty() )
        {
            Node *current = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete current;
        }
    }
    char & front()
    {
        return head->data;
    }        
    const char & front() const
    {
        return head->data;
    }        
    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &, const LinkedList & );
};

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const LinkedList &lst )
{
    for ( LinkedList::Node *current = lst.head; current; current = current->next )
    {
        os << current->data;
    }

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s( "Hello World!" );
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    LinkedList lst( s );
    std::cout << lst << std::endl;

    while ( !lst.empty() )
    {
        std::cout << lst.front();
        lst.pop_front();
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World!
!dlroW olleH
!dlroW olleH
```

Comment: I get errros when I compile this with gcc

Comment: @REDLIGHTER It seems you did not correctly copies and pasted the code I showed. What errors did you get?

Comment: nullptr was not declared in this scope error - line 26 – RED LIGHTER 27 mins ago   
     
" - line 48 ranged based for loops are not allowd in c++98 - nulptr not declared line 24 – RED LIGHTER 26 mins ago

Comment: @REDLIGHTER Try to use NULL instead of nullptr.